# How to customize Team Explorer in VS

Tags: visual-studio

I have re-installed my Visual Studio 2019 Professional and now Team Explorer is missing some sections. `Branches` and `Changes` sections are missing. Now I am able to manage my branches from Git repository window, which is not too comfortable for me. How can I add missing sections to Team Explorer tab?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solves. New "Git experience" feature has been presented in VS 2019.
To bring disappeared sections back in Team Explorer just disable "New Git user experience" under Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Preview features.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/git-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 1):

Yes just uncheck New Git features!
[image]